# How to use Oracle regexp_like to identify rows where column contains any of list of characters

Tags: sql, regexp-like

I have a table where I need to identify rows where a column named LONGDSC contains any of the following characters _*%?:;=()[]/\|#."

I have tried many different iterations, but I am having no success. I would appreciate any assistance.

```
select * from tablex where REGEXP_LIKE (longdsc, '^[_/*%?:;=()[]\\/\|#."]*$');
```

Comment: You have to be clearer on "I am having no success". What is the problem you're having? From a guess, i think you're missing the escape "\" on the special wildcard characters like "|" ,".", "*", "?", "(", ")", "[", "]"

Comment: By no success, I mean I am getting no results at all. I know there are rows that meet the desired criteria/ I have tried several different permutations and have no gotten the expected results.

Comment: I will try adding the escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I did not need the escape characters, or the ^ *$.  The one issue I did encounter was the character ], I had to move it to the front immediately after the opening [. I am getting the results expected. I am getting all rows with at least one of the items in the list between '[     and      ]'.

```
select * from tablex where REGEXP_LIKE (longdsc, '[]:_*%?;=()/\|#."[]');
```